# Define a symbolic unit vector in SymPy

Tags: python, vector, normalization, sympy

Let say I want a `n`-component symbolic real unit vector, where `n` can be any integer number, let say `n=3`. That is:

[image: Formula]

So far I'm stacked at this very basic point: 
`v = Matrix(symbols("v:3", real=True))`

How can I code the normalization condition?

Comment: Mathjax isn't enabled on this site, I've added a screenshot (made on https://www.mathjax.org/#demo) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such assumptions (the sum of squares is 1) are not supported in SymPy. You'll just have to use the equation `Eq(v.norm(), 1)` in some way, at whatever step of computations requires using the information that `v` is a unit vector. It's probably easier for SymPy to use the equation in the form `Eq(v.norm()**2, 1)`, without the square root. The details depend on what you want to compute with that vector.